# Hot corner problem in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, compiz, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

I use Ubuntu 18.04.
I've installed Compiz wth default functions and Tweak-Tool Settings.
Use Adwaita-Dark theme.
When I disable hot-corner in the settings it turns off, but after lockscreen  it's working again.
How can I turn off it in a hard way?
And how to turn on all windows screen in four fingers up on touchpad?

Comment: Are you using Unity desktop or gnome-shell ?

Comment: Same here, using Unity desktop. Workaround for me was to run `unity-tweak-tool`, go to Window Manager > Hotcorners, then turn off/on the toggle, but that's a hassle.